# UWP Custom Panel sized based off the Panel Childrens arranged height

Tags: c#, uwp, custom-controls

I'm currently trying to create a control that act's similarly to a VariableGridView however instead of Item heights and widths precalculated with Column/Row spans, the content would control the items Height. With a Column span deciding the controls width. You can find a WIP sample [here](https://github.com/JSmyth886/UWP-Samples).

The only issue I'm currently having is the initial load of the control. When the control is in a ScrollViewer and it's height exceeds the window/parent's height it doesn't scroll. See below:

[image: Scrollbar fills the right hand side]

However once I resize the window, the scrolling works correctly as expected. See below:

[image: You can see here the scrollbar has fixed itself and is the right size for the content of the Panel]

It might be hard to see but if you look at the darker part of the scrollbar on the righthand side you can see it's not sized itself correctly on the initial load.

I suspect I'm making a mistake in the controls `MeasureOverride` method however I can't see what I'm doing wrong:

```
 protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize) {
   // Need to use this method LimitUnboundedSize as when within a 
   // ScrollViewer an infinite height is supplied within the availableSize
   var desiredSize = LimitUnboundedSize(availableSize);
   UpdateColumnOffsets();
   foreach (var child in Children) {
     child.Measure(desiredSize);
   }
   return desiredSize;
 }

 private Size LimitUnboundedSize(Size input) {
   if (Double.IsInfinity(input.Height)) {
     var scrollViewer = this.FindAscendant<ScrollViewer>();
     var contentHeight = scrollViewer.ViewportHeight.Equals(0)
       ?  Window.Current.Bounds.Height : scrollViewer.ViewportHeight;
     input.Height = (contentHeight >= GetMaxOffset ? contentHeight : 
       GetMaxOffset);
   }
   return input;
 }
```

How can I calculate the height my items are going to take up before I set the size of my Control?

Comment: I can see the difference after download your app. The problem seems due to you set something when initialize and the GetMaxOffset is always much higher than contentheight after you resize the UI. When initialize the GetMaxOffset is 10 but after that it never backs to original. Why don't just let the height as Infinity?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't let the height be infinite, it will crash if it's infinite. Quoting from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/boxpanel-example-custom-panel) - "However, the panel itself can't return a Size with an infinite value from MeasureOverride; that throws an exception during layout."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my own issue. I needed to figure out the placement of my cards before the arrange. That way the columnOffsets will be calculated and I can base the height of the panel off the max column offset.

I haven't updated the github repo yet, but here's the code that needs updated for this to work:

```
protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize) {
  foreach (var child in Children) {
    var resizable = child as IArrangeable;
    resizable?.Arrange(pointDictionary.GetValueOrDefault(resizable.Card));
  }
  return finalSize;
}

private double GetMaxOffset {
  get { return columnOffsetY.Max(); }
}

protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize) {
  var desiredSize = availableSize;
  UpdateColumnOffsets();
  foreach (var child in Children) {
    child.Measure(desiredSize);
    CreateOffsetCache(child);
  }

  if (Double.IsPositiveInfinity(desiredSize.Height))
    desiredSize.Height = GetMaxOffset;

  return desiredSize;

}

private Dictionary<Card, Point> pointDictionary;

private void CreateOffsetCache(UIElement child) {
  var arrangeable = child as IArrangeable;
  if (arrangeable == null) return;
  var card = arrangeable.Card;
  var useColumnOffset = columnOffsetY[card.Column] < columnOffsetY[card.Column + card.ColumnSpan - 1] 
    ? columnOffsetY[card.Column + card.ColumnSpan - 1] : columnOffsetY[card.Column];
  var point = new Point(columnOffsetX[card.Column], useColumnOffset);
  pointDictionary[card] = point;
  SetColumnOffsetY(card.Column, card.ColumnSpan, child.DesiredSize.Height);
}
```